# Need to change PortalAlias from a website url to localhost in Dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have a website in DNN with multiple portals in it.we need to configure its Development environment so we have restored its source code and database.but when we try to run source code it redirects to portalalias table Httpalias column value i.e  values urls stored of portal. we need it to run on localhost. we have replaced that portalalias Httpalias value to localhost but it doesn't work

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you've made the changes correctly to the portal alias table, what is likely happening is that the old portal aliases are still stored in application memory. Restarting the site or application pool in IIS should do the trick.